# Whether a field extension contains $i$.

Tags: galois-theory

For which values of n does the cyclotomic extension over $Q$ contain $i$?

My guess is that this is precisely when n is divisible by 4. If n is divisible by 4,then i can show this quite easily. But is the converse true? I haven't been able to figure out a counter example or a proof.

Comment: Are you talking about extensions of $\Bbb{Q}$ or square roots of $-1$ in general?

Comment: Yes I should have clarified. I am talking about extensions of $Q$.

Answer (score 1):

a cyclotomic field generated by $n^{th}$ roots  will contain $i$ if $x^2+1|x^n-1$

a simple argument based on long division shows that $n$ must be even. suppose $n=4m+2$ then:
$$
x^{4m+2} - 1 =(x^2+1)(x^4m - x^{4m-2}+\cdots +(-1)^{2m}) -2
$$
whereas 
$$
x^{4m} - 1 =(x^2+1)(x^{4m-2} - x^{4m-2}+\cdots +(-1)^{2m-1}) 
$$

Comment: Just one question. How do you say that x^2 + 1 divides x^n - 1? 
I can say that since $i$ is contained in it,so is $-i$, because of normality. And so,the splitting field of $x^2 + 1$ is contained in the cyclotomic extension. But does that imply the divisibility relation?